# How to ask for peer feedback on a free MVP of a pm related product here?

Tags: discussion

I asked for a peer feeback of a free MVP product related to project / product / portfolio management and my post got flagged as spam and deleted. No chance to chat with the unhappy parties as far as I can tell. So my question is how to ask you guys for your feedback on pm.stackexchange? What's wrong with my request in the first place? Thanks!

Piotr

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an answerable question about project management.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! Your last post was only a promotion for that product, which is why it was deleted as spam. You can read through some [tips here](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) which would explain how to not have posts deleted as spam. As for this question, I'm not really familiar with this particular SE site, but since this is a question about the site itself, not a question about project management, I would ask on [PM meta](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) instead.

Comment: This site is for q&a, not for chat or marketing. VtC

Comment: "Why was my question flagged?" seems to me like a valid meta question, rather than marketing.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange isn't the right place for every question. Most stack sites, and PMSE in particular, are focused on *canonical* answers about a topic rather than soliciting opinions, feedback, or discussion. There are a couple of exceptions such as Software Recommendations and Code Review, but in general questions are expected to have a canonical answer and to benefit future visitors, and not just the person asking the question.

Software reviews (whether your software or not) are not within the scope of our site. Questions here must be about the profession or practice of project management, and should be about solving a particular problem. Asking about soliciting reviews or any kind of market research are about as  far as you can get from our acceptable list of topics.

I didn't see your original post, so I have no idea what was in it. However, based on the fact that you also posted this question on the main site rather than on meta indicates that you are new to both PMSE and Stack Exchange in general.

I'd certainly recommend [taking the tour](https://pm.stackexchange.com/tour) and reviewing our [help page](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure that you're participating effectively within the PMSE community. We're glad to have you, and will be glad to answer any on-topic questions you may have.

Comment: [This](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/22911/the-portfolio-goggles-for-jira-a-call-for-feedback) was the OP's original question.

Answer (score 1):

PM:SE is for practical problem in project management; you're asking for feedback on a solution.

It is permissible to ask a question and then answer your own question.  *IF* you revise the second paragraph of your question into a real problem statement, then you could post that as a question.  "How do cooperating groups of companies maintain a portfolio of shared goals?" (you'd have to make that a practical goal and describe why it is a problem).

Then you could post your product as an answer, and treat alternative answers as part of the discussion.

**[You need to reveal your affiliation](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)**; be very transparent.

If you do this in a way that looks like marketing/spam, it will be closed as spam and your reputation will suffer. (both your SE rep and your public reputation). You'll be perceived as someone who prioritizes marketing over community rules & preferences - like the guy who stands on a chair at a Birthday Dinner to sell multilevel marketing products.  That would be a bad thing.

If, on the other hand, you're genuinely interested in the *problem*, then you could post the problem. Your answer to that problem is as legitimate as mine.

Comment: This is good advice. I didn't see it anywhere in the Help Center, though. Am I just missing it, or...?